# Is it possible to run locally JRuby on Google App Engine without restarting server on every change?

Tags: ruby, google-app-engine, jruby, sinatra, restart

Unfortunately, GAE requires restart of the server on each code change.
Is it possible to prevent it and have immediate feedback after code save?

Or, can I import Google App Engine's API into my ruby code and run it on Sinatra server? Tried this but it fails on "import com.google.appengine.api" (it doesn't know what 'com' is).

For Sinatra, I use "Rerun" ( http://github.com/alexch/rerun ) which restarts server immediately after a change with minimum wait.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, seems like JRuby on Rails doesn't need server restart, Sinatra reloaded/shotgun plugins didn't work well for me.

To run it I copied the files from http://rails-depot.appspot.com/src (the source @ http://code.google.com/p/appengine-jruby/source/browse did not contain all the files).

Answer (score 1):

Try http://github.com/rkh/sinatra-reloader